# Trackpad 1 pair with windows 10

Tags: bluetooth, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I'm using windows 10 on my MBP, and my trackpad (Bluetooth) won't work, unless I disable the bluetooth, then it works... So, how can I have both trackpad and bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

So, I solved it by going back to OSX, removed the trackpad from the Bluetooth settings, then disabled bluetooth. I paired the trackpad with a tablet to test, and it paired, so I logged back to windows 10, then it paired with the '0000' code.

Strange, but it worked.

Comment: If your trackpad's problems persist, ckeck if you have installed the correct Boot Camp drivers that Apple provides for support of Apple trackpads, mice keyboards, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, when asked to enter pin, use "0000" then press enter on the keyboard and click the trackpad immediately.

It worked for me.

Comment: How is this question different than the previous question?  See [answer] for info on answering questions here.  Unless you [edit] your answer to include significantly different info, you risk having this question deleted.